# Bootstrap : Mouse-enter animation issue with img-responsive [Opera only]

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

**Situation :** I've got following, simple jQuery code :

```
 $('img').each(function()
        {
            $(this).mouseenter(function()
            {
                $(this).css('opacity','1');
            });
            $(this).mouseleave(function()
            {
                $(this).css('opacity','0.4');
            });
        });
```

with CSS rule :

```
    img
    {
        opacity: 0.4;
        transition: all 0.5s;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    }
```

Which is used to add simple opacity change animation (on hover) to images :

`<div class="well"><img src="" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>`

https://jsfiddle.net/k4afv6fk/1/

**Problem :** The img-responsive class seems act little buggy here - every time the animation goes on, the image is being rescaled (about 1px) few times before returning to original size. It does not looks great.

**Question :** Is there any way to prevent that 1px scaling when img-responsive object is being animated? The problem does not occurs without img-responsive class but I expect this image to be responsive :)

@Edit : I've just figured out, that problem only occurs under Opera browser. Is there any way to improve code to work on Opera properly as well?

Comment: Why not use :hover? Mouseenter and mouseleave still leaves the :hover untouched unless you strictly defined a different behavior for that. Not to mention, you are not telling it to do anything on focus. Do you not want the opacity effect to happen when people tab into it?

Comment: Not that it is related to the solution, but why exactly do you use that jQuery code? It looks like you don't need it at all. This is a simple hover effect and can easily be achived by a single line of code in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

This can be as said previously be done without using javascript

CSS:

```
   img
    {
        opacity: 0.4; //include this css lastly, and if this doesn't work add !important
        transition: all 0.5s;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    }
 img:hover{
    opacity:1; //include this css lastly, and if this doesn't work add !important after 1
    }
```

HTML :

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="http://joombig.com/demo-extensions1/images/gallery_slider/Swan_large.jpg">
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/k4afv6fk/

Comment: I've changed jQuery code to this simple :hover rule, however the problem still occurs. Maybe It is connected with the fact, that image is inside <div class="well"> section?

Comment: i don't beleve, and please get jquery out of this code, with css it's faster cuz you're using hardware acceleration :)

Comment: I've already replaced jQuery code with CSS, but as you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/k4afv6fk/1/ , when the image is inside <div class="well"> its buggy :(

Comment: The fiddle you sent me at my side works perfectly :)

Comment: I've just opened it in Firefox and it works like a charm... Looks like the bug is only visible in Opera browser. I assume that's impossible to improve since its the browser fault?

Comment: I'll check it out now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100264/discussion-between-marko-mackic-and-baka1408).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
img
{
    opacity: 0.4;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

**P.S.** Prefixed properties should be before the unprefixed ones. (and please check our comments on using `:hover` instead of that jQuery code.)

Comment: I've changed jQuery code to this simple :hover rule, however the problem still occurs. Maybe It is connected with the fact, that image is inside <div class="well"> section?